# Sinatra server won't start - "wrong number of arguments"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I wanted to try Sinatra as I've heard it's better for the newbie web-dev than rails.. and in general I prefer more minimalistic than not.

To premise this, I'm using ruby 2 and whatever version of sinatra that gem install gets.

All I've done so far is the basic

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    'Hello, World!'
end
```

try to run the server with ruby basics.rb and it throws this at me:

```
/home/ch35hir3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/server.rb:108:in     `initialize': wrong number of arguments (4 for 0..3) (ArgumentError)
from /home/ch35hir3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-    1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:14:in `new'
from /home/ch35hir3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack    -1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:14:in `run'
from /home/ch35hir3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1488:in `start_server'
from /home/ch35hir3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1426:in `run!'
from /home/ch35hir3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

Of course I tried googling the error, and just general poking around but I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `thin` gem is a `pre` version. Removing that gem and using thin 1.6.0 should fix the problem. `gem uninstall thin && gem install thin`. Alternatively, you could use a different server, like puma. `gem install puma`, then under `require 'sinatra'` add `configure { set :server, :puma }`

Comment: Thanks! I had heard about puma as being a pretty good server, and wanted to use that at some point. Guess now is good as any!