# Sinatra on thin with rackup not starting

Tags: ubuntu, sinatra, daemon, thin, rackup

I'm using the following code to start my app as a daemon,

```
rackup = " sudo rackup --port #{PORT} --host #{HOST || 'localhost'} --pid /var/run/#{NAME}.pid -O NAME[#{NAME}] -D"
exec "(cd /#{ROOT} && exec #{rackup})"
```

but it doesn't actually start, It loads all the files in (I can see from the logs) but no `.pid` file is created. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

As a side note, does `NAME['app_name']` mean I can then use `sudo pkill app_name` to kill the daemon?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a bug with thin, after fiddling I got it to display an error message, after some poking around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579984/sinatra-server-wont-start-wrong-number-of-arguments), I installed thin 1.6.3 and it fixed the problem, now I just need to work out why I can't access the site, then I can try deploying it.

EDIT: Turns out I was setting it to the wrong host, should have been '0.0.0.0' rather then 'localhost' even though I did do `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` in my main app